# How to play an audio signal in matlab controlling the left and right channel of earphone on Matlab individually?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I am doing audio signal processing in matlab. As a part of my project, I am playing recording audio signal, processing it, and playing it in real-time. Now, the output that I am sending through the two channels, I want that to be processed differently, and want to plot the graphs as well.

Basically, I want the left ear to hear a differently processed signal than the right ear and plot it as well.

Even if it is not in real time i.e. any stored signal (.wav,etc) will be helpful.

Any help will be appreciated (don't have much time :().

Comment: Which instruction do you use for the playing? Usually the input is a two-column matrix, where each column is one channel (left/right)

Comment: I'm using audioplayer for playing the sound signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a stored .wav file, you can use `wavread` to import, which will import the file as a two-column array. If you call this array `A`, you could manipulate the left channel using `A(:, 1)` and the right channel using `A(:, 2)`.

If you're using `audiorecorder` to record the audio, you'll have to change the number of channels from 1 to 2 so that you record in stereo. The default is mono.

**EDIT:** To plot in realtime, you can work off of the following function I wrote. The function takes the amount of time you want to record as its input `runtime`. It creates a timer `timerID` and continuously acquires the audio data from the recorder object and plots it, using `drawnow` to refresh the figure. If you wanted to do any processing, you could do it in the loop right before the `plot` commands.

```
function audioPlot(runtime)
timerID = tic;
recObj = audiorecorder(44100, 24, 2);
record(recObj);
h(1) = subplot(2, 1, 1);
h(2) = subplot(2, 1, 2);
while (toc(timerID) < runtime)
    if recObj.TotalSamples > 0
        audioData = getaudiodata(recObj);
        plot(h(1), audioData(:, 1))
        plot(h(2), audioData(:, 2))
        xlabel(h(1), 'Left Channel')
        xlabel(h(2), 'Right Channel')
        drawnow
    end
end
stop(recObj);
end
```

Happy to answer any questions!